# How do I add the graph control in the Visual Studio toolbox

Tags: c#, graph

I have been developing Generic setup planning application in visual studio 2012. I need to use  graph control in my application. Can some one suggest me some effective solution for the same. Is there any way to add graph control in visual studio 2012 toolbox ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237(v=vs.110).aspx <- this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click in the Toolbox, select Choose Items, and then select the following namespaces in the .NET Framekwork Components tab:

```
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting

System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
```

Answer (score 0):

hello this functionality is only available in Visual Studio Ultimate.

Comment: the above is correct and it can also be used in Visual Studio 2012